# EWS FindItem CalendarView weird handling of MaxEntriesReturned

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

This is my SOAP FindItem call to retrieve calendar items:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
      <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
      <typ:TimeZoneContext>
        <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
      </typ:TimeZoneContext>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
         <mes:ItemShape>
            <typ:BaseShape>AllProperties</typ:BaseShape>
            <typ:AdditionalProperties>
              <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:LastModifiedTime" />
            </typ:AdditionalProperties>
         </mes:ItemShape>
         <mes:CalendarView MaxEntriesReturned="1000" StartDate="2015-02-18T00:00:00Z" EndDate="2015-12-05T23:59:59Z"/>
         <mes:ParentFolderIds>
           <typ:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
             <typ:Mailbox>
               <typ:EmailAddress>sddress@server.nl</typ:EmailAddress>
             </typ:Mailbox>
           </typ:DistinguishedFolderId>
        </mes:ParentFolderIds>
      </mes:FindItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The MaxEntriesReturned in the optional element

```
 <mes:CalendarView MaxEntriesReturned="1000" StartDate="2015-02-18T00:00:00Z" EndDate="2015-12-05T23:59:59Z"/>
```

is supposed to mean [the maximum number of results to return in the FindItem response](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564515%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

However:

1) The results easily returns more items:

```
<m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
   <m:ResponseMessages>
      <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
         <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
         <m:RootFolder TotalItemsInView="2516" IncludesLastItemInRange="false">
            <t:Items>
               <t:CalendarItem>
```

(and note the `IncludesLastItemInRange="false"`, so there are more items. Then why return 2516?)

2) If I leave `MaxEntriesReturned="1000"` out of the query, I get a `ErrorServerBusy` response code with text *The server cannot service this request right now. Try again later*.

This may have to do with [Exchange Server throttling policies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mstehle/archive/2010/11/09/ews-best-practices-understand-throttling-policies.aspx), but that link says:

> The EWSFindCountLimit parameter specifies the maximum result size of FindItem or FindFolder calls that can exist in memory on the Client Access server at the same time for this user in this current process

so I expect to get the `ErrorExceededFindCountLimit` response code with text *You have exceeded the maximum number of objects that can be returned for the find operation. Use paging to reduce the result size and try your request again.*

The issues I have with these observations:

1) I specify `MaxEntriesReturned` to prevent being overwhelmed with data, yet **I get much more than I ask for**. (Fine with ice cream, but not here).

2) If I do indeed bump into a throttling policy I'd like a decent `ErrorExceededFindCountLimit` **response that tells me what is going on**, so that my code can suggest corrective measures; `ErrorServerBusy` can mean many things.

What can be done about both?

This is all testing against Release to Manufacturing (RTM) [version of Exchange Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx):

```
<ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="516" MinorBuildNumber="29" Version="Exchange2013"  .../>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `TotalItemsInView` attribute in the `FindItem` response corresponds to the **total** number of items in the entire CalendarView. The resulting dataset will still be bound by the set `MaxEntriesReturned` if you take a look at the actual amount of items returned.

So for instance, if I set `MaxEntriesReturned` to 1 for a date range I **know** has 4 events total, I'll get back: `<m:RootFolder TotalItemsInView="4" IncludesLastItemInRange="false”>`. But in the response, only one `CalendarItem` is returned.

[Note added by OP] That solves Item 1) of the question ([item 2 is in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29142676/512728))

Answer (score 1):

Not content with waiting for an answer, I kept digging and came across [Throttling Policies and the EWSFindCountLimit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/03/12/throttling-policies-and-the-ewsfindcountlimit.aspx).

This explains issue 2) ([item 1 is in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32462837/512728))

The article says *If the call has a RequestServerVersion that is earlier than Exchange2010, you will receive a failure response with an error code of ErrorServerBusy.*

That was exactly what I was doing: `<typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>`. Changing it to `<typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>` returns:

```
<m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
   <m:MessageText>You have exceeded the maximum number of objects that can be returned for the find operation. Use paging to reduce the result size and try your request again.</m:MessageText>
   <m:ResponseCode>ErrorExceededFindCountLimit</m:ResponseCode>
   <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
   <m:MessageXml>
      <t:Value Name="PolicyLimit">1000</t:Value>
   </m:MessageXml>
</m:FindItemResponseMessage>
```

... nicely telling me that the limit I broke was 1000.

The article concludes: *the moral of the story is: Always use a paging mechanism when calling FindItem or FindFolder*

Answer (score 1):

The CalenderView isn't page-able eg have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.calendarview_properties(v=exchg.80).aspx and you will see that there is no property that allows you to specify an offset (or index) value.

What you need to do is reduce the time window so you get less then 1000 items returned. Then page the timewindow manually yourself to get the full Appointment list you want.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this. It has a MaxEntriesReturned. I specify that (to prevent getting slapped with errors) together with StartDate. I get **more** than MaxEntriesReturned entries **with IncludesLastItemInRange=false**, so some limit seems to be applied. I implement my own paging mechanism with subsequent calls with a new StartDate as long as IncludesLastItemInRange=false.